# Find specific value in a range then hide all rows below it vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a table with headers starting at cell B4 to N4.
Cell B4 says hours and below it - from cell B5 to B28 - I have hours from 1AM to 12AM. Based on cell AF2's value, all the rows below that cell value will be hidden. For example, cell AF2 says 4PM. 5PM to 12AM will be hidden. 1AM to 4PM will remain visible. Please help

```
Sub HideRows()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim time1 As String

time1 = Range("AF2").Value
Columns("B:B").Select
Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:=time1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Cell Is Nothing Then
    'do it something


Else
    Cell.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
   'Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

`

Comment: And what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: I need to hide all rows below the value indicated on cell AF2 until row 28

Comment: yes, you've stated what you want to do. We still don't know what you have tried and where the problem is.

Comment: updated the question with what I have so far

Comment: I'm lost at the else part

Answer (score 0):

First, you really want to [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code.

```
Sub HideRows()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim time1 As String

time1 = Range("AF2").Value
Set Cell = Columns("B:B").Find(What:=time1, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
    Rows(Cell.Row & ":" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

Side note: You probably also want to qualify all your ranges with the worksheet they are in. Something like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AF2").Value`, `Set Cell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B").Find(...` and so on

Comment: This hides all rows below... I only need to hide a few rows.. I have 6 tables with the same setup in columns B:N. The 6 tables all have hours on column B and I need to loop through all those columns

Comment: This is moving the goal post. Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1507398/edit) to include all constraints